# PHP always emailed before but now it's not sending emails. Anything wrong here? Something change?

Tags: php, forms, email

```
    if($formok){
    $headers = "From: NOREPLY@boweng.com\r\n";
    //$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $emailbody = "
        <html>
            <head>
            </body>
        </html>";

    mail("myemail@boweng.com","Registration",$emailbody,$headers);
}
```

This is the code that has always worked. Have there been any changes that makes this code outdated or something? Should quotes be re-arranged?

Comment: Check what the response is from `mail()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I was wondering how I could check what was going on with GoDaddy mail server. Do I need to login to GoDaddy?

Comment: I should note I'm running linux on GoDaddy

Comment: The `mail()` function returns true if it worked, and false if it didn't. If it returns false, you have a PHP configuration problem. If it returns true, it's not related to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I owe everyone who took the time to even look at this an apology! There is an issue with our firewall/mailserver - I tried a different email, which I should have a long time ago (wasted hours on this), and it worked just fine. Thank you all.